# Frequency modulation and communication between two microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, communication, 8051

I have good progamming skills and concepts on 8051 microncontroller. People suggest me to work on PIC and ARM micro-controllers but I want to make some small projects on 8051 and later move on to complex micro-controllers.

I have decided to do some wireless operation using two micro-controllers. Well the idea is to send certain information from one micro controller to other micro controller. for example I would give some input to one microcontroller like some hex value 55H and that micro controller should send this input value to the second micro-controller and  the second microcontroller should perform the operation based on the input value I  have given.

Well I guess, I require some FM transmitter and reciever IC's in my circuit design but to be honest I dont know what type of FM IC's I should prefer. I could not find a better notes on the internet about FM IC's.I just saw infrared techniques using micro controller but its only for short distances may be 10 meters.

Could any one kindly provide me some links on FM transmitter and receiver IC's and  how to use the FM IC's with 8051 micro-controller in transmitting and recieving its data to other micro-controller using FM techniques.Thanks

Comment: may be this would be useful.
however I'm not working for lankatronics.
http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&p=10723#p10723

Comment: related: [What do I need for a basic RF circuit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42923/what-do-i-need-for-a-basic-rf-circuit)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interessted in the microcontroller stuff I suggest to use pre-built transmitter and receiver modules (e.g. working at 433MHz frequency; look e.g. [here](http://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/acatalog/FM_Radio_Modules.html)) that can be easily interfaced to microcontrollers.

If you are interested in designing transmitters and receivers, this is a whole new field, a science of its own.

Comment: yaa I need RF modules and circuit interfaced with 8051